# jquery is not functional?

Tags: javascript, jquery

firefox (v52.0), jquery

this works:

```
// example 1
$('html').find('body')
```

this works:

```
// example 2
var h
h=$('html')
h.find('body')
```

This doesn't work:

```
// example 3
var f
f=$('html').find
f('body')
```

I get

> Error: Permission denied to access property "ownerDocument"

why?

but this works:

```
// example 4
var a
a = x => $('html').find(x)
a('body')
```

Comment: part of the problem is knowing what to ask,

Comment: I agree, I don't think this is a duplicate, although the linked answer gives a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example 3 doesn't work because `find` is called on the global context when you assign it to `f`. If you use `call` and pass in a valid `jQuery` object as the context, the code works. Try this

```js
var f = $('html').find;
console.log(f.call($('html'), 'body').length)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, example 4 works because `a` can be translated to the following code, if written without an arrow function.

```
var a = function(x) {
  return $('html').find(x);
};
```

It's just example 1, but with a wrapper function in order to take a parameter

Comment: that seems to work.  but what does that error message mean?

Comment: I actually get a different error message, _"this.pushStack is not a function"_. I know that this error is because the _this_ context is not a valid `jQuery` object. Maybe, your error is also something to do with the context being wrong.

Comment: I think you answer is correct. javascript  `this` is confusing me.

Comment: Read [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#nothing-but-rules) for a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

No, jQuery is not functional

By looking at jQuery core source code:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L51

You could see it hold state in `this`.

In `f=$('html').find`, the `this` of `f` is changed and no longer the `this` holding `$('html')` state

--

In this case, you are just proxy the method call. The `this` of `find` no change.

```
var a
a x => $('html').find(x)
a('body')
```